# Laravel 5.4 how to get Articles related to a Category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm building a simple shop catalog in Laravel 5.4. Basically, what I want is to have a button on my article that gets all articles with the related categories (noting that an article can have many categories).

I have my Article and Category models, as well as an article_category pivot table. Both have a belong to many relationship to the other, like:

Code in Article model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

Code on Category model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

My issue is how to get the list of articles that include all articles with categories related to an article.

This is my function on the controller right now, it receives a JSON object with a list of categories:

```
public function showRelatedArticles($category) 
{
    // Decode JSON to PHP array
    $category = json_decode($category);
    $collection;
    if(is_array($category)){
        foreach ($category as $cat) {
            $articles = Article::whereHas('Category', function ($query) {
                $query->where('category_id', $cat->id);
            })->get();
            $collection = merge($articles);
        }
    } else {
        dd('Not array');
    }

    return view('front', ['articles' => $collection]);
}
```

This returns an error:

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Category()

I may have the wrong type of relation between my models, but this is the correct method of declaring a Many to Many relationship, no?

Comment: `whereHas('categories',`?

Comment: Thanks Felippe Duarte, you might be onto something, I should be using 'categories' instead of 'category'. Unfortunately I cant seem to use $cat inside the function, it gives me an 'undefined variable' error. passing a second parameter to the function seems to break it, how should I proceed?

Comment: `function ($query) use($cat) { `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the whole part to this:

```
if (is_array($category)){
    $category_ids = collect($category)->pluck('id');

    $articles = Article::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
        // Assuming your category table has a column id
        $query->whereIn('categories.id', $category_ids);
    })->get();
} else {
    dd('Not array');
}
```

Note the lowercase `categories`, which is the function name in the `Article` class.

This combines the `in` from the queries, the `collect` for array's and only retrieves the articles which are linked to the given categories.

Comment: This gives me an 'undefined variable $category_ids' on the $query->where('id', 'in', $category_ids); Maybe it goes out of scope when entering the function?

Comment: @TianRB Yes, I forgot the use part after the function. Added it!

Comment: Well it's definitely moving forward! I'm getting an error 
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `articles` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join `article_category` on `categories`.`id` = `article_category`.`category_id` where `articles`.`id` = `article_category`.`article_id` and `id` = in))

Comment: Great! change the `where('id', 'in'` to `where('categories.id', 'in'` and we should be there!

Comment: @TianRB But we're not. I forgot that in 5.4 it's `whereIn` instead if `where(... in`. Updated the answer.